# How to fetch the translation of multiple words with Google Translate

Tags: java, google-translate

I need to fetch the translation from a list of words.

I tried using this API that uses Google translator: https://github.com/goxr3plus/java-google-translator/blob/master/pom.xml

However, by for looping the words and calling the service `translation = GoogleTranslate.translate("en", entry.getKey());`
All I get is a 429  (I'm assuming Google doesn't like this many requests.

But I can't seem to find a way of calling the service with the list (No idea why google hasn't thought about this?)

Any solution? I don't have to use google per se, any accurate translator would be fine!

Edit: Trying sending multiple words like word::word::..... but google's return is random and not parseable (they'll randomly remove colons commas spaces, and even forget to translate certain words in the list)

Answer (score 0):

Performing an API request inside of a loop results in an absurd number of API calls in a very short amount of time. Instead, concatenate the list of words into a single String with a delimiter, send it to the proper API endpoint for translation, and parse the returned value into whatever data structure or format you need it in.

Comment: See https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/advanced/batch-translation#using_a_tsv_file